# Not able to launch WebdriverIO in Ubuntu command line

Tags: linux, selenium, ubuntu, error-handling, webdriver-io

I followed these steps to install Webdriver on a linux machine (*Ubuntu*).

- Create directory: `mkdir webdriverio-test && cd webdriverio-test`
- Download selenium standalone server:
  `curl -O http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.5/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar`
- Download `gheckodriver`:

`curl -L https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.16.0/geckodriver-v0.16.0-linux64.tar.gz | tar xz`

- Start selenium webdriver: `java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar`
- Create a `test.js` script:

---

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }
};

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
    .end()
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

- Finally, run the above script in a different terminal window, while `selenium-server-standalone` is running in the other window.

> ***!!! Problem:*** After I run the command, the script is failing, although it is opening the Mozilla browser. What am I doing wrong?

- Stack-trace error:

[image: errors screenshots]

Answer (score 0):

Try with chromedriver:

1. Go to folder with your test:

```
cd webdriverio-test
```

2. Download chromedriver:

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_linux64.zip

unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

3. Start chromedriver:

```
./chromedriver -port=4444 -url-base=/wd/hub -verbose
```

4. Open new terminal window and run test:

```
node test.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion but I made it work, just changed the selenium standalone  and gecko driver version to the latest one.